# I have created a form and after getting the data storing it in an array and want to display in a table below the form

Tags: angular

I have created a form and after getting the data storing it in an array and want to display it in a table below the form. But I am not able to display the data in the table only the first value is getting shown up in the table.

this is my app.component code

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
    
    export interface Add{
      title:string;
      name: string;
      category: string;
     }
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      naam="Naman";
      advertisment:Add[]=[];
      localItem:any;
      category = ['Furniture','Hardware','Mobile'];
       tb=false;
      constructor(){
        //  if(this.localItem==null)
        //  {
        //    this.advertisment=[];
        //  }
        //  else{
        //   this.advertisment=JSON.parse(this.localItem);
        // }
      }
      ngOnInit(){
        //this.advertisment=JSON.parse(this.localItem);
      }
      advertismentForm = new FormGroup({
        title: new FormControl(''),
        name:new FormControl(this.naam),
        catgory:new FormControl('')
      });
    
      onSubmit(){
        console.log(this.advertisment);
        this.advertisment.push({
          title:this.advertismentForm.get('title')?.value,
          name:this.advertismentForm.get('name')?.value,
          category:this.advertismentForm.get('catgory')?.value,
    
        });
        this.tb=true;
        //localStorage.setItem("advertisment",JSON.stringify(this.advertisment));
      }
    
      dataSource=this.advertisment;
      displayedColumns: string[] = ['title', 'name','category'];
      
    
    
    }
```

this is my html

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
      {{advertismentForm.value | json}} 
       
      <h2>Advertisment Form</h2>
      <form [formGroup]="advertismentForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Title</label>
          <input formControlName="title" type="text" class="form-control" >
        </div>       
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>   
        <div class="form-group">
          <select formControlName="catgory" class="form-group">
            <label>Category</label>
            <option *ngFor="let cat of category" [value]="cat" class="form-control">{{cat}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
       </form> 
    
        <div>
          <table mat-table #mytable [dataSource]="dataSource" *ngIf="tb" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    
            <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
                  The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->
          
            <!-- Position Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Title </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </td>
            </ng-container>
          
            <!-- Name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
            </ng-container>
    
            <ng-container matColumnDef="category">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Category</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.category}} </td>
            </ng-container>
          
          
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
          </table>
        
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vogx.png) as you can see data is getting into array but not in table only getting first value.

Answer (score 1):

Add yout this.dataSource=this.advertisment to the ngOnInit()

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
    
    export interface Add{
      title:string;
      name: string;
      category: string;
     }
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      naam="Naman";
      advertisment:Add[]=[];
      localItem:any;
      category = ['Furniture','Hardware','Mobile'];
       tb=false;
      constructor(){
        //  if(this.localItem==null)
        //  {
        //    this.advertisment=[];
        //  }
        //  else{
        //   this.advertisment=JSON.parse(this.localItem);
        // }
      }
      ngOnInit(){
        this. dataSource=this.advertisment;
        //this.advertisment=JSON.parse(this.localItem);

      }
      advertismentForm = new FormGroup({
        title: new FormControl(''),
        name:new FormControl(this.naam),
        catgory:new FormControl('')
      });
    
      onSubmit(){
        console.log(this.advertisment);
        this.advertisment.push({
          title:this.advertismentForm.get('title')?.value,
          name:this.advertismentForm.get('name')?.value,
          category:this.advertismentForm.get('catgory')?.value,
    
        });
        this.tb=true;
        //localStorage.setItem("advertisment",JSON.stringify(this.advertisment));
      }
    
      dataSource=this.advertisment;
      displayedColumns: string[] = ['title', 'name','category'];
      
    
    
    }
```

Your is my html

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
      {{advertismentForm.value | json}} 
       
      <h2>Advertisment Form</h2>
      <form [formGroup]="advertismentForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Title</label>
          <input formControlName="title" type="text" class="form-control" >
        </div>       
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>   
        <div class="form-group">
          <select formControlName="catgory" class="form-group">
            <label>Category</label>
            <option *ngFor="let cat of category" [value]="cat" class="form-control">{{cat}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
       </form> 
    
        <div>
          <table mat-table #mytable [dataSource]="dataSource" *ngIf="tb" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    
            <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
                  The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->
          
            <!-- Position Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Title </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </td>
            </ng-container>
          
            <!-- Name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
            </ng-container>
    
            <ng-container matColumnDef="category">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Category</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.category}} </td>
            </ng-container>
          
          
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
          </table>
        
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing your new rows to this.advertisement, but displaying dataSource in the table. After pushing the new row in your submit-function, add this line:

```
this.dataSource = this.advertisement.slice()
```

This will update the reference on the array used for the table, so it should pick up that the data is updated.